# Can I transmit to several FM radio channels concurrently using one digital transmitter?

Tags: microcontroller, rf, frequency-modulation, digital-modulation

I have an [Si4720](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si4720-21-B20.pdf) that can transmit at one FM radio frequency at a time, and if I use several of them on my board, I would be able to transmit at several FM radio frequencies at the same time. This solution is not feasible for me (due to board size and cost limitations) so I would like to know if the following makes sense, and if it does, which hardware and software (ideally a combination of a micro-controller and an RF unit) I would need to implement it:

1. Generate the information signal (human voice recording, so limited to about 4kHz)
2. Generate `N` carrier signals (ideally, `N=101`, corresponding to the number of FM radio channels in the USA)
3. Modulate
4. Transmit

This is for an extremely low power application (effective service range of less than 200ft) so licensing is not an issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, N = 100 is the correct number -- 88.1 MHz thru 107.9 MHz, 200 kHz spacing.

Comment: Just as a note; broadcast stations in the USA don't use adjacent channels in any local area.

Comment: How were you planning on generating the n carrier signals?  You only have a single RIN and LIN port - were you going to try to combine the audio information prior to inputting them to the '4720?

Comment: You might be interested to read about [orthogonal frequency domain multiplexing (OFDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiplexing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The approach that I would probably take would be to use a small-to-medium size FPGA to do the DSP (basically 100 DDS generators), a high-speed (250 MHz) DAC, and a reasonably good LC bandpass filter at the output of the DAC.

---

This could be interesting: I did some digging, and it is now possible to do general-purpose programming on the GPU in a Raspberry Pi, and it is also possible to use the (hidden) DPI interface to drive a VGA display. Therefore, it might be possible to do this entirely on a Pi Zero, with the only external hardware required being the bandpass filter mentioned above.

Comment: This seems to work for me. I find the idea of just using the Pi Zero with a bandpass filter very attractive since I can *hopefully* do all the work in software. I  will start with the code posted here
[link](http://www.icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Turning_the_Raspberry_Pi_Into_an_FM_Transmitter)
and will see if I can modify it to generate a carrier signal at several frequencies. Thanks.

Comment: Well, no, that's still going to be limited to one carrier at a time. The approach I'm talking about would be to do the DSP (100 DDS, etc.) on the GPU and then use the DPI/VGA interface as the high-speed DAC.

Comment: You're right. I was hoping that I could generate N carrier signals and modulate the audio completely in software by modifying the C code in the link in my previous comment but it doesn't seem possible after reading the explanation in more detail: "... it sets the clock generator module to enabled and sets it to output on GPIO4. It also sets the frequency to 100.0Mhz, which provides a carrier."
As you mention, I'm going to investigate if I can use some DSP library to generate the carriers and modulate, and then hope there is a GPIO I can use to output the composite signal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only have a single LO in that chip.  So I don't see how you can generate multiple FM outputs at the same time.

Comment: With *that* chip, no.  But an IQ upconverter having sufficient bandwidth could transmit multiple signals generated at offset baseband rates, especially if they were closely packed in a portion of the band.